# Unable to create a google container cluster

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I get the following error while trying to create a google container cluster.

> An unknown error has occurred in Compute Engine: "EXTERNAL: Google
>   Compute Engine: Required 'compute.zones.get' permission for
>   'projects/access-jobs/zones/europe-west2-c'". Error code: "18" RETRY

Can someone please help me out. I am new to google cloud platform

Comment: Can you create a VM directly in europe-west2-c? Have you enabled the compute API (by visiting the compute engine page in the cloud console)?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, it looks like you do not have the `compute.zones.get` permission in the `access-jobs` project. This permission is required to get information about a zone in GCE.

> Required `'compute.zones.get'` permission for
>   `'projects/access-jobs/zones/europe-west2-c'`"

## [Enabling the Google Container Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/quickstart#before-you-begin)

You will need to enable the API. You can visit [this](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/kubernetes/list) URL which will ask you to choose a project and then wait for a few minutes before the API is enabled. After that, you will be able to create the Container Clusters.

## IAM Roles and Missing permissions

If you're still getting this error even after enabling the API, you might actually have a permission issue.

1. You can look at the [list of Compute Engine IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#iam_roles) to understand the list of permissions any given role has. The account you use to access Google Cloud Platform needs to be granted one of these roles which provides `compute.zones.get` permission. For creating Cloud Clusters (i.e. Google Container Engine (GKE) clusters), you most likely will need more permissions than just this one. You can look at [GKE IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/iam-integration#iam_roles) to understand better which role would be most suitable. You can also look at the second option.
2. Use an account which has been granted project owner / project editor role, so that you can edit your project freely. You might have to check with your project owner/admin if you're not one to get this role granted just like option 1.